# Sitecore Social Connected Goal Updates Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-social-connected

I'm researching Sitecore's Social Connected module, and am trying to tie a social update to a marketing goal.  Sitecore's [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/social/11/social_connected_administrators_and_developers_guide_11-usletter.pdf) states:

> In the **Marketing Center**, on the **Publish** tab, click **Updates**.  The **Update** tab appears.

When I click **Update**, I get an alert window stating: "You do not have permission to see any item reports."  I get this alert both when signed in as a developer or as Admin, so it appears not to be security related.

I'm running Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 120427) with Social Connected Module 1.1.0 rev. 120329.

**Updates:**

- The Update button is mapped to the command "social:tab:show" in Core database item */sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Social/Updates*.
- "social:tab:show" is linked to "Sitecore.Social.Publishing.Commands.SocialCenter" in *Sitecore.Social.config*.
- Here's the code that's sending the alert:

```c#
public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
{
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) context, "context");
      if (context.Items.Length != 1)
        return;
      if (WebUtil.GetFormValue("scEditorTabs").Contains("social:tab:show"))
      {
        SheerResponse.Eval("scContent.onEditorTabClick(null, null, 'OpenSocialCenter')");
      }
      else
      {
        Item obj = Context.Item;
        if (obj == null)
        {
          SheerResponse.Alert("You do not have permission to see any item reports.", new string[0]);
        }
        else 
        [code continues]
```

- I subclassed Sitecore.Social.Publishing.Commands.SocialCenter so I could set a breakpoint. Here are the values I'm seeing during execution:

  - Sitecore.Context.Item is null.
  - context.Items has one item, the Goal item that is open in the Marketing Center.
  - `WebUtil.GetFormValue("scEditorTabs")` returns an empty string.  The code appears to expect "social:tab:show".
- Using Sitecore 6.5 build 3 does not resolve the issue.
- The update button **does** work correctly for regular content items (as opposed to goals).  However, the documentation clearly states that this button is to be clicked on the Marketing Center tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message appears if you open the Marketing Center from the Sitecore menu.  Instead, open the Content Editor application, and navigate to `/sitecore/system/Marketing Center`.  If you do not see `/sitecore/system` in the content tree, go to the View menu and select Entire Tree.  When a goal is accessed through the Content Editor, the Publish/Updates button works correctly.

Note: I have confirmed this issue occurs with Sitecore 6.5.0 (rev. 111230), update 3, the most recent update approved for Social Connected, per the [release notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Social%20Connected%20Module/Social%20Connected%201,-d-,1/Release%20Notes.aspx).

**Update**: This bug has been fixed with Social Connected v1.2.